# Linux File Protection

Tags: linux, security, livecd

How can I protect my linux box from any physical access to my files and folders. When you protect your linux, a user can use LiveDVD or mount to another bootable PC and access to all content of your info. How can we protect linux specially in Embedded applications?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first port of call will be a solid password and permissions policy. This includes root and user passwords and ensuring users only have access to what they need. Encryption will help with physical attack if you encrypt you entire drive to require a password on start-up.

When it comes to live CB/USB boot, you can set a BIOS password to prevent an order change or boot devices. Since I have no idea what system you have you will have to look up how to do this. Once you have done these two things the only issue you can face after this is someone stealing your hard drive and booting it via a caddy on another machine.

To prevent boot password resets (unplug and remove the cmos battery) I suggest you lock your system to ensure they can't be opened by users.

Answer (score 0):

For any security policy, you first have to know that perfection is impossible. Next consider what the treats are, and what they are after.  Nosy highschoolers or a determined profesional make quite a difference. What are they after, how much is the cost to you if they succeed. This determines how much effort to invest, and in what. If an attacker has physical access, you can do very little. Otherwise, just using standard policies (select passwords carefully, use a Linux distribution, install only what is needed, use it's security tools) will go a long way.

Comment: I think we have to change File system, but I don't know how?

Comment: @q123456, the only realistic way of doing that is to install again. But why?